# ghostscript gives undefined in --execute-- when using color.tex with pstricks on plain tex

Tags: color, pstricks, plain-tex, postscript, ghostscript

Assume the following plain TeX file:

```
\input pstricks
\input color
\pscircle{1.5}
\bye
```

Compiling using eTeX works fine, dvips too. However the resulting PS file can't be processed using gs, I'll post the error message if needed. When *not* using the color package, the processing flow works OK. The difference between the two generated Postscripts files is:

```
<  0.8 SLW 0. setgray   0.0 0.0 2 copy moveto 42.67911 0 CLW mul round
< sub dup 0 rmoveto 0 360 arc closepath  gsave 0.8 SLW 0. setgray  1.
< .setopacityalpha   0  setlinejoin 0  setlinecap stroke  grestore end
---
>  0.8 SLW gray 0   0.0 0.0 2 copy moveto 42.67911 0 CLW mul round sub
> dup 0 rmoveto 0 360 arc closepath  gsave 0.8 SLW gray 0  1. .setopacityalpha
>   0  setlinejoin 0  setlinecap stroke  grestore end
```

i.e. one time "0. setgray" is used, the other time "gray 0". I tried to clarify, if "gray" is a valid Postscript command, according to what I found, the usual way to define a color is "setxxx".

Still I'm not 100% if this is an issue in color.sty or an issue in ghostscript. Could you give me a short hint? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Ghostscript are you using?

Comment: This is Debian unstable: 9.27~dfsg-3

Comment: I can at least reproduce this. Also in Debian; same version of gs.

Answer (score 2):

PSTricks needs at least the defined color `black`, which itself is internally defined as `\black` which itself expands to `0 setgray`. But only if it is defined. However, this works:

```
\input pstricks
\input color
\newgray{black}{0}
\pscircle{1.5}
\bye
```

the problematic part is in `color.sty`:

```
\ifx\color@gray\@undefined
  \ifx\color@rgb\@undefined
  \else
    \definecolor{black}{rgb}{0,0,0}
    \definecolor{white}{rgb}{1,1,1}
  \fi
\else
  \definecolor{black}{gray}{0}
  \definecolor{white}{gray}{1}
\fi
```

For some historical reasons, PSTricks defines by default the color `\black`.
`\color@gray` is not defined so color does  a
`\definecolor{black}{gray}{0}`  which is passed into the ps file instead
of `0 setgray`.  However, there is no real need for using package `color`.
One can set the colors with the PSTricks macros for plainTeX.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a gs issue (the generated PostScript is error)

It works in latex as (I think) xcolor is loaded in that case even if not explicitly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}


\pscircle{1.5}

\end{document}
```

Grayscale colours work in plain normally as well

```
\special{color push gray 0.5}
on two
\special{color pop}
three four

\bye
```

the dvips special (with the arguments coming after the color command) gets converted to the PostScript

```
0.5 TeXcolorgray
```

which is more or less just the primitive PostScript call

```
 0.5 setgray
```

The way the color package works is that normally it holds the internal color in "driver-specific special syntax" so gray is `gray 0.5` black is `gray 0` etc and when needed latex will do `\special{color push \current@color}` and the right code is generated.

But here the interface to convert to pstricks internal form so pstricks is outputting black as `gray 0` instead of calling the infamous command `\c@lor@to@ps` which always showed up as undefined if you tried to use pstricks with pdflatex .

`\c@lor@to@ps gray 0` here would call `\c@lor@ps@gray 0` which expands to `0 setgray` which would work.

Comment: see my edited answer. No real need to change anything in color or PSTricks ...

Comment: @user187802 thanks for the investigation.